# Import Error of TensorFlow in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, visual-studio-code

I work on the python code in VS Code for image processing and i need to use tensorflow. When I want to import tensorflow i get this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

> E0401:Unable to import 'tensorflow'

I have read [ImportError: No module named tensorflow for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568346/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-for-visual-studio-code) but it is used for working with GPU but I only want to work with CPU.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried importing tensorflow in another environment? Like in a simple terminal or another IDLE?

Comment: Yes, i install tensorflow with following command: pip3 install tensorflow

Comment: That's good but did you check that the import works outside of VS Code?

Comment: Yes, In terminal I execute the code with python3 command and it works correctly but when I use it in VS Code I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an [environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for your python project.

After that, you should [install `tensorflow` with `pip`](https://medium.com/@ddcreationstudi/install-tensorflow-with-virtuelenv-and-visual-studio-code-on-mac-6b9f93f0fb08).